# Electron Preload vs Electron Main

Tags: node.js, electron

I am currently using Electron v16. Apparently on this version, we cannot use built-in Node modules in the renderer thread anymore.

The only way to do it is by using electron-preload.js.

I've read this resource:
https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2022/using-nodejs-apis-in-electron-with-react/
where the author placed the implementation code in electron-main.js by utilizing the `ipcMain` and the code is invoked through electron-preload.js `contextBridge`.

My question is:
Is there any difference if put the entire implementation code in `electron-preload` instead of having the need to invoke an event from here and send it to `ipcMain?`

Here is the code from the author:

**electron-preload.js:**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  blenderVersion: async (blenderPath) =>
    ipcRenderer.invoke('blender:version', blenderPath),
  },
});
```

**electron-main.js**

```js
ipcMain.handle('blender:version', async (_, args) => {
  console.log('running cli', _, args)
  let result
  if (args) {
    const blenderExecutable = checkMacBlender(args)
    // If MacOS, we need to change path to make executable
    const checkVersionCommand = `${blenderExecutable} -v`
    result = execSync(checkVersionCommand).toString()
  }
  return result
})
```

I am thinking if doing something like this instead is acceptable (pros/cons?):

**electron-preload.js:**

```js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  blenderVersion: async (blenderPath) =>
      console.log('running cli', _, args)
      let result
      if (args) {
        const blenderExecutable = checkMacBlender(args)
        // If MacOS, we need to change path to make executable
        const checkVersionCommand = `${blenderExecutable} -v`
        result = execSync(checkVersionCommand).toString()
      }
      return result
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, there is no difference between the two at all...

That said, separating the calling of your code from its implementation goes a long way in "Separate your Concerns". If you have a lot of calls from render to main (or vice versa), your `preload.js` script will become huge. Trying to manage a file of that size, especially if you are [using typescript](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#usage-with-typescript) in your Electron application can become problematic. The overhead of such declarations will grow and grow.

I take an even more thorough, but in my mind, simplified approach...

I use the `preload.js` script purely as a place to declare "channel names" and implement the communication between the main process and the render process(es) via the use of pure [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) handles such as:

- [ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)
- [ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)
- [ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args).

Having such a simple script means I only need to manage one `preload.js` script and I use it in every window I ever create.

---

This is my `preload.js` script. To use, just add your "channel names" to whatever whitelisted array you need to. EG: In this instance, I have added the channel name `test:channel` for use only between the main to render process.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'test:channel' // Our channel name
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

In my `main.js` script, just IPC with the channel name and any associated data, if any.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('test:channel', 'Hello from the main thread') })
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

Finally, in your render just listen for the channel name and implement functionality when called.

`index.html` (render process)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test"></div> // Outputs "Hello from the main thread"
    </body>

    <script>
        window.ipcRender.receive('test:channel', (text) => {
            document.getElementById('test').innerText = text;
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

To use this `preload.js` scipt in the main and render processes, the following implementation would apply.

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

> Remember, you can't return functions, promises or other objects that can't be serialised with the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm). See [Object serialization](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#object-serialization) for more information.

Comment: This goes against the principle of context isolation and is unsafe. It defeats the purpose of setting it to true. Please read https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation

Comment: @CyrilGupta Can you please explain how the above method is unsafe? Electron methods are not directly exposed, arguments are used and channel names are checked against a white list before running. Further security could be implemented in the domain controller(s) if desired. See Electrons [Security considerations](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations) and [Enable Context Isolation for remote content](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content) for more information.